# How to read and process a local file using Web Server for Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I did set up the temporary server connecting to my local directory using **Web Server for Chrome**. I want to read line by line, and parse html files in that directory upon the click event of some button. I want something as follows:

```
<input type="button" onclick="parse('\someURL\somefile.html')">
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: <a href = "Your URL" ></a>

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this

```js
onclick="location.href='\someURL\somefile.html';"
```

Comment: You're just redirecting the current page to somefile.html, but I want to somehow pass the file to parse() function to parse it